# Sort by option is disabled in standard knowledge component

Tags: lightning, knowledge, lightning-knowledge

[image][image]I have added standard knowledge component to Case record page and when I click on Sort by button all options looks disabled. I am unable to sort knowledge articles by relevance and others.

Comment: A screenshot might be helpful as I'm not clear on what you're asking or expecting.

Comment: @KrisGoncalves added screenshot

Answer (score 0):

The "Sort by" option is available only when you actually search for articles in the component. If you type some string in the search bar and click enter you'll find that you can sort the results. It doesn't actually apply to "Suggested Articles" which is what your screenshot is on and the default view that loads when you're on a case.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=knowledge_lightning_sidebar.htm&type=5
[image]

Comment: Thanks Kris Goncalves. Useful to me.

Comment: How advance search behaves. Because when I set filters and click apply it will not show any knowledge articles in the surface. We have to type text in search bar and click enter then only it shows search results. Is this standard behavior?

Comment: What do you mean by "advance search"?

Comment: I have added image in this question

Comment: Yes that's normal behavior. Think of it as a filter for results from your search (for which you need to actually search for some text)